# Resampling of MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-resample

I would like a daily breakdown of a dataset by type.  There are not records for every day for every type, where they don't exist I would like NaN.

I'm able to get a 'resampled to daily' result, but the type is ommitted.

The code below should be a fully working example (well, working apart from the known error at the end!):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': [dt.datetime(2021,1,1), dt.datetime(2021, 1, 3), dt.datetime(2020,1,2)],
    'Type': ['A', 'A', 'B'],
    'Value': [1,2,3]
})

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
#   this loses the 'type'
print(df.resample('1D').mean())

df = df.reset_index().set_index(['Date', 'Type'])

#   this raises an exception "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'"
print(df.resample('1D').mean())
```

Output I'm looking for is a row for every day / type combo:

| date | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20210101 | A | 1 |
| 20210102 | A | NaN |
| 20210103 | A | 2 |
| 20210101 | B | NaN |
| 20210102 | B | 3 |
| 20210103 | B | NaN |

Any advice or pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need resample per groups is possible use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for resample per days and then for add missing values is used [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['Type', pd.Grouper(freq='1D', key='Date')])['Value']
        .mean()
        .unstack()
        .stack(dropna=False)
        .reset_index(name='Value')
      
      )
print (df)  
  Type       Date  Value
0    A 2021-01-01    1.0
1    A 2021-01-02    NaN
2    A 2021-01-03    2.0
3    B 2021-01-01    NaN
4    B 2021-01-02    3.0
5    B 2021-01-03    NaN
```

If need only append missing datetimes per groups is used [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Type'].unique(),
                                  pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max())], 
                                  names=['Date','Type'])
df = df.set_index(['Type','Date']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df)                
  Date       Type  Value
0    A 2021-01-01    1.0
1    A 2021-01-02    NaN
2    A 2021-01-03    2.0
3    B 2021-01-01    NaN
4    B 2021-01-02    3.0
5    B 2021-01-03    NaN
```

Comment: Fantastic! Using your first sample, to 'flatten' it, I simply add .reset_index() at the end.  Correct?

Comment: @GinjaNinja - I find better solution, so removed first old one.

Comment: @GinjaNinja - If want use `df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)` remove `key='Date'` in `pd.Grouper`

Comment: I deleted my comment saying there was an exception as I realised I needed to remove the set_index.  Thanks for your very clear help